# Cambiar color de fondo(background) de lista (AlertDialog) al seleccionar una opción, y que se mantenga al volver a abrir

Tags: android, recyclerview, alertdialog, customadapter

Tengo dudas de como hacer un `alertdialog` custom, donde pueda hacer que cuando seleccione un item del alertDialog al volver a abrir tenga el background de otro color, indicando que este item, fue seleccionado, y si selecciono otro item, ese se coloree y el anterior item, vuelva a su estado normal...

```
String[] lista = {"1","2","3","4","5"}

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity_main_panel.this);
    builder.setTitle("titulo");
    builder.setItems(lista, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });


AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Imagen Ilustrativa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, DarckBlezzer Ya solucionaste esto?

Comment: Ya pude resolver el problema, aunque no se si sea una forma correcta de hacerlo, ya que tenga tiempo, subo mi respuesta.

Comment: Te preguntaba  ya que si no lo habías solucionado agregar una opción de como realizarlo.

Comment: Podrías explicar, también, para los que no saben, como yo, que busque un montón... y en ingles, y se que es fácil, pero no para los que vamos empezando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Este es un ejemplo también para los que tenían este problema, espero que les sirva a todos...

**Variables Globales**

```
//Solo va a ser alert.show en el botón
AlertDialog alert;
//Variable para saber cual es la opción seleccionada
int posicionSeleccionada =-1;
```

**Función para declarar todo lo que lleva la lista y no declararla mas veces...**

```
//Funcion que conlleva la creacion de ListAdapter, alertidalog.Builder y alertDialog
public void declararListView(){
    //custom, lista de contenidos aleatorios, podria mandarse a esta funcion la lista
    String[] lista = {"aeroplanos", "animales", "carros", "colores", "flores", "cartas", "mounstros", "numeros", "sombras", "sonrrisas", "deportes", "estrellas" };

    //se asigno un xml customisable, tambien se puede agregar una imagen a el.. o otras cosas
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, lista) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView titulo;
        }

        @Override
        public int getPosition(@Nullable String item) {
            return super.getPosition(item);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //si convertView es null, creamos su cuerpo
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.titulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                // vista definida, obtener la vista
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //poner texto a textview
            holder.titulo.setText(getItem(position));

            //declarar todos los textview y linearlayout a su color por default
                //cuerpo de textview - seria el linearlayout
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(0);
                //Cambiar color por defecto de textview, se debe especificar color
                holder.titulo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                //hace clicleable el item
                convertView.setClickable(false);

            // si es la pocicion seleccionada, se cambia el color del cuerpo y del textview
            if(position == posicionSeleccionada){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.titulo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                //hacer no clicleable el item
                convertView.setClickable(true);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Lista");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int itemPosicion) {

                    //obtenemos el texto directanente de DialogInterface, en vez de usar variable global...
                    ListView lw = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView();
                    Object checkedItem = lw.getAdapter().getItem(itemPosicion);

                    //imprimimos el texto de lo que se selecciono
                    System.out.println(checkedItem.toString());

                    //tambien se puede obtener texto del adapter, pasando la posicion
                    //adapter.getItem(i);

                    //asignamos la posicion a la variable global del item que se selecciono
                    posicionSeleccionada = itemPosicion;

                }
            });
    //boton negativo para cancelar
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //cerrar lista
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert = builder.create();
}
```

**Función y botón para llamar**

```
//todo esto lo puse en onCreate
declararListView();

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      if(alert!=null)
          alert.show();
  }
});
```

**Archivo list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/cuerpo"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text=""
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Imágenes de ejemplo**

[image]
[image]
[image]

> Nota: Espero que esto le sirva a todos, si tienen algún problema por favor preguntar...